# Constructing a png file out of multiple images and labels

Tags: ios, swift

I have a few `UIImageViews` and `UILabels` that you can drag around the screen in an editor.
The images are png's with a very high resolution (>2400px ) but on screen *they might appear smaller*.

I would like to produce a png file out of that screen ( which includes labels and images at certain positions), which will hold the **actual** sizes of these images (>2400px) .

If I just capture the screen programmatically (render), he will produce an image in the size of the screen, and it will not be transparent.

How can I construct the png file by my self by placing images and texts in whatever sizes and positions I want?

This for example :

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "example.png") {
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("copy.png")
        try? data.write(to: filename)
    }
}
```

will **not** let you specify locations or add multiple images and texts to the file

Answer (score 0):

Found a pretty simple and sweet way to do so, first you save in a dictionary all your screen elements, then you can simply add them to a file with :

```
let font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 160)
let showText:NSString = "hello world"
// setting attr: font name, color...etc.
let attr = [NSFontAttributeName: font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blue]
// getting size
let sizeOfText = showText.size(attributes: attr)

let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image!.size.width,height: image!.size.height)


UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height), false, 0)

// drawing our image to the graphics context
image?.draw(in: rect)
// drawing text
showText.draw(in: CGRect(x: rect.size.width/2.0, y: rect.size.height/2.0, width: rect.size.width, height: rect.size.height), withAttributes: attr)



// getting an image from it
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```